# else path not taken on a try catch block

Tags: jestjs

disclaimer: this is part of a course I am taking and a practice task. I am having quite hard time wrapping my head around the test chapter of a course I am taking. Given the following class, I have to write test to it but I see the error else path not taken on my return results; line. Which else is it talking about?

```
import DB from './DB';
import ErrorLogger from './ErrorLogger'; // ===> if path not taken here

class ChapterSevenJest {
  constructor() {
    if (!ChapterSevenJest.instance) {
      ChapterSevenJest.instance = this;
    }
    return ChapterSevenJest.instance;
  }

  _db = new DB();

  getData = async (gradeId, teamId) => {
    let results = [];
    try {
      results = await this._db.getData(gradeId, teamId);
    } catch (error) {
        ErrorLogger.register(
        error
      );
    }
    return results; // else path not taken here
  };
}
const JestPractice  = new ChapterSevenJest();
export default JestPractice;
```

the test:

```
import DB from './DB';
import ErrorLogger from './ErrorLogger';
import JestPractice from './JestPractice';

describe('service', () => {
  const gradeId = 11;
  const teamId = 1;
  let spyLogs;

  beforeEach(() => {
    spyLogs = jest.spyOn(ErrorLogger, 'register');
    spyLogs.mockReturnValue(true);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    spyLogs.mockReset();
  });

  it('should return data ot a grade and team', async () => {
    const spyDB = jest.spyOn(
      DB.prototype,
      'getData'
    );

    const stat = [
      {
        "score" : 100,
        "rank": 2
      }
    ]

    spyDB.mockResolvedValue(stat);
    const results = await JestPractice.getData(
      gradeId,
      teamId
    );

    expect(spyDB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(gradeId, teamId);
    expect(results).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(results[0].score).toStrictEqual(100);
    expect(results[0].rank).toStrictEqual(2);
  });

  it('should return empty on error', async () => {
    const spyDB = jest.spyOn(
      DB.prototype,
      'getData'
    );

    spyDB.mockRejectedValue('error');
    const results = await JestPractice.getData(
      gradeId,
      teamId
    );

    expect(spyDB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(gradeId, teamId);
    expect(results).toHaveLength(0);
    expect(spyLogs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
     "error"
    );
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 if statement which is

```js
if (!ChapterSevenJest.instance) {
  ChapterSevenJest.instance = this;
}
```

You need to have a test where `ChapterSevenJest.instance` is truthy so that the `if` block doesn't execute.

Comment: thanks Mansour. I didn't look at it that way but makes sense. Why wasnt it marked as not covered though? Also any tip on how to reach the if block?

Comment: I remember with lcov html reports it would have an `E` indicating the `else path not taken`. 
To cover it, you can potentially try setting `JestPractice.instance` to a value which would make it truthy thus skipping the `if` block.